# What is the difference between address size(width) and addressability?

Tags: memory-address

What I understand so far is address width is the number of bits in an address.

For example, 4 bits width address can have 2^4 = 16 cases. And what I'm really uncertain is addressability. Based on what I learned is "the size of the most basic unit that can be named by address". So,  if we have 4 bits address width and 2 bits addressability, what happens?

I've been really curious about it for a couple of weeks, but still bummer.
Could you guys explain those things by drawing or something?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. "the size of the most basic unit that can be named by address" is the byte size of the machine, it has nothing to do with the address size.

Comment: The addressability of a machine is the size of the most basic unit that can be named by an address I just copied that from my lecture note. one missing thing is "of a machine". is it a big deal?

Comment: OK, so it sounds like this is the same thing as byte size. Anyway, this isn't a programming question, it's a computer science question. Try cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: 2-bit addressability is something that probably does not even exist. Quoting your definition,"the size of the most basic unit" is typically either 1 byte, 2 bytes, 4 bytes or 8 bytes. The smallest addressable unit that can be addressed (and retrieved/updated) is usually called a word. If you have 4-bit address and 2-byte words, then you can access 16 words, to the total memory size of 32 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do get it.  There is the number of address bits, the width if you will, and there is the size of the unit those things address.  so 8 bits means you have 256 things, 16 bits of address 65536 things.  The size of thing is completely independent of the number of address bits.  From a programmers perspective almost always we deal in units of bytes, so 8 bits of address would be 256 bytes, 32 bits of address would be 4 gigabytes.  As you dig into the logic it is often wasteful to use a byte based address, if you have a peripheral that has 32 bit wide registers and you can only access those as whole 32 bit registers then do you need to connect address line 0 or 1?  often not.  so at that peripheral the address bus however wide it is (often the whole address bus to the peripheral is a subset of the address bus higher up closer to the processor/software, and those address bits are in units of 32 bit words.

To make things even more confusing, memory parts are often defined in terms of bits, even if they have an 8 or 16 bit data bus.  So you might have a 4M part but that is megabits not megabytes...

Comment: Related question. The Intel 8086/8088 both had an address width of 20 bits. But its registers were 16 bit. Why would each memory location have 4 bits more than the registers could store?

Comment: @DeanP to get 16 times the address space.  Not atypical to have some form of solution to add more address bits than the addressing (general purpose) registers can reach.  I dont know if it is unique to intel but instead of just adding 4 bits somewhere they instead did the 16 bit segment register thing so you could have significantly more flexibility in how you address things.  Very clever

Comment: I think you are 100% correct. Check this link. Pins 16 - 19, the 4 extra pins that I mentioned, indicate whether to access the extra, stack, code, or data segment. These are the segements you mentioned and what adds the flexibility. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pin-diagram-8086-microprocessor/#:~:text=Intel%208086%20is%20a%2016,DC%20supply%20for%20its%20operation.

Comment: the address is computed inside using a segment register based on the instruction/mode.  or instruction pointer plus code segment for fetches.  In the intel docs.